# white screen when running ionic 2 app on device

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

When I run my test app on my Android device, I always see a white screen and app does not execute further. I used `ionic run android --device`  on CLI to run the app.

Further to see which error stops the app from showing up, I used `ionic run android --device -l -c` . When app runs with this command, I see this error coming up `OBJECT[OBJ GLOBAL] has no method '__zone_symbol_requestAnimationFrame'` 
Currently I am running my app on a phone with Android version 4.2.2.
Any idea as to why this kind of error is showing up? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use crosswalk plugin if you're on 4.2.Ionic 2 minimum version support is 4.4 and above.